# pulseaudio "alias" sink, backed by (runtime switchable) other sink

Tags: microsoft-teams, pulseaudio

Since MS Teams for linux only enumerates audio devices on startup, I have to restart the application when switching e.g. to my headphones. As a workaround, I'd like to create a persistent "alias" sink in pulseaudio, which I can re-route to any real sink on the fly (e.g. like `pactl move-sink-input` or the pavucontrol sink selection), without the application noticing.

Pulseaudio has some modules for "backing" sinks with others (for different purposes) but they all appear to fix the backing sink on startup: Tried `module-combine-sink`, `module-remap-sink`.
With `module-null-sink` I can create a virtual sink and have its output as "monitor" source, but I cannot get this source back to a (real) sink like my headphones.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm not answering your question, but this might help you work around your original problem.

I use ms teams in Google Chrome (I'd prefer Firefox, but teams calls don't work in FF). Then:

1. Some of the changes in devices will be enumerated and reflected, if not, a simple refresh is enough and is much easier than closing and re-opening the standalone application
2. The "Skype is using microphone" annoying problem is no longer observed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!